# How to handle an else function in a nested if statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a nested if statement in a template:;

```
{% if object in request.user.mymodel_set.all %}
    {% if object.pk == request.session.field_pk %}
        Selected
    {% else %}
        <form method="POST" action="myURL" class="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Select">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

However the `<input>` does not render. It does when the parent `{% if %}` statement is removed. Am I missing something as to how the `else` statement is handled in this template?

Comment: Are you sure `object in request.user.mymodel_set.all` is `True`?

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
{% if object in request.user.mymodel_set.all %}
   {% if object.pk == request.session.field_pk %}
    Selected
   {% elif object.pk != request.session.field_pk %}
    <form method="POST" action="myURL" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

if this is not work too maybe the variables you check in your conditions not True

Comment: please flag as answer to help others find this easly : )